# What is the difference between running a command as logged in as a user vs doing sudo -u

Tags: command-line, server

I am wondering about the difference between running `$userA: command line` and `$userB: sudo -u userA command line` in the linux terminal.

Is there any specific things that cause the file being created. Like creating deb file, it should not use sudo permissions when running dpkg-buildpackage.

Comment: Are you sure you mean `user command line`? I cannot think of the time when i'd do that. The file you execute must always come first. Did you by any chance mean "`command line` as logged in as a user"?

Comment: Pardon me, I mean running command line under a specific user that has specific permission, like user under sudoers group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to remember is that there are two things that come into play when a command is run:

1. What is the user's permissions in that case.
2. What is the environment that the command is ran in.

When you log in as a specific user you change both of these, but when you are using `sudo -u` you simply change the first aspect.

Consider this, assuming a clean install:

(running as userA):

```
vim /home/userA/test
```

(and now as userB):

```
sudo -u userA vim /home/userA/test
```

Both commands will work perfectly, and you may not notice an error until much later on. Because in both instances `vim` needed to crate a directory for its configuration files. It was running with permissions of **userA** so that will be the owner of the directory, but in the first case the directory will be created in its correct place: `/home/userA/.vim`, but in the latter case there will be a problem, the environment was still pointing to userB's home directory, so `/home/userB/.vim` has been created with the wrong permissions.

If you try to start some other applications, like file managers (which create thumbnails, logs, etc) you will have many files all over the place, which have the wrong owner and permissions.

---

You can note that `pwd` displays your home directory and try the following on your computer:

as userA:

```
pwd
sudo -u userB pwd
```

both should give you `/home/userA/`, even though the second is running as userB

however, login as userB and then:

```
pwd
```

You will now see `/home/userB/`

Comment: Thanks the answer. Hope this help another human being.

Comment: @Abdul If you think that this answer is helpful, please consider accepting it as a correct one. There should be a checkmark that you can click.